# How do I mount this towel rack that was ripped off the wall?

Tags: bathroom, mounting, bathroom-fixtures, patching-drywall

One of my tenants sent me a pictures of my broken towel rack. What would be the most cost effective fix?

[image]

Comment: Well, firstly you need to tell your tenant to stop using the towel rail as a handrail ... That large of a hole in the wall implies the rail was originally properly installed using a decent drywall anchor, and sufficient force was applied to rip it through the drywall. it can certainly be repaired, but without major wall surgery not much can be done to make it strong enough to double as a handrail.

Comment: I would try to reinstall it using one of the Wingit anchors. Whether this could be done would depend on the spacing of the screws in the metal wall bracket for this towel rack. Wingits are intended for grab bars. Towel racks are considered to be properly installed with simple plastic drywall anchors, but these often fail in rental properties or under ordinary use by teenagers or other oblivious people.  For towel bars I installed 24" grab bars in our house screwed into studs, but this limits the location of the towel bar. The next towel bar I install I intend to try a Wingit.

Comment: Note that there are a number of different Wingit anchors and the lowest level is what I would consider for a towel rack. The one I would try requires a 3/4" hole in drywall. Get the pkg of 6 and use them as needed. You will need a special drill bit to drill a rather large hole in the drywall. Two of these cannot be placed closer together than the size of the hole would allow. https://www.walmart.com/ip/MASTER-Wall-Anchor-10-32-x-3-1-2-PK6/173051356?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=1122&adid=22222222227042837547&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=106983583517&wl4=au

Comment: Title is incorrect:  Towel rack was pulled out of the wall.  Charge tenant for repairs.

Comment: The original installation might have been substandard so I would not charge the tenant unless you know for sure there was abuse. However, the practical realities of the landlord tenant relationship must be a guide.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - I'd agree with Jim Stewart on the practical realities. Tell your tenant not to do it again, sure, but charging for a 50p / 50c replacement anchor and a few minutes labour? I'd rather keep a good relationship with my tenants, as long as they're not causing bigger problems.

Comment: @SharifBhuiyan - FYI your towel rail is on upside-down. You shouldn't be able to see the grub screws (/set screws or whatever name you know them by) from above. More an aesthetic comment than anything important.

Comment: Re: The tenant relationship points—A friend of a friend had a tenant who, for uncited reasons, dumped concrete in the toilet. The guy later "spent a fortune" fixing that. This same landlord apparently gives all of his tenants the month of December for free, as a Christmas gift, because he said 1) it eliminates the otherwise guaranteed struggle with late rents in January, and 2) his tenants love him for it. I'm not sure if the toilet concrete and the free-December epiphany are related, but there is a lesson here in picking your battles with tenants, especially over just a few dollars.

Comment: FWIW: I think attaching this type of fixture to drywall is a hopeless task. Drywall fixings depend on spreading the load, but these rails have two holes very close together on each mounting plate so you get a lot of leverage on the top fixing  that's pulling on a small weakened area and thus has little strength. I would replact it with something mounted from a single point in the stud. Blaming the tenant here is unreasonable as even bumping against this would have broken it over time.

Comment: People sometimes trip in the bathroom and may hold on to a handrail-like object. There is nothing wrong with that and the tenant is not at fault; obviously has no particular interest in measuring the wall mount strength of the racks, or doing press-ups with a low hand rail.

Comment: For a rental property, I would mount a 1x4 (solid wood, like hemlock, fir, or pine) across the section where the towel rack goes, screw it to the studs (and if you cover the hole, you don't have to patch right away), and then mount the towel rack to that. Sand it nice and smooth first, round the front-facing edges and corners, and paint it the trim color (or possibly the wall color) and it should look ok. The towel rack will hold much better if screwed to solid wood.

Answer (score 31):

The traditional solution for a pulled out towel rack is to remove the towel rack, patch the holes (usu two on each end) and place the rack slightly higher or lower. An experienced or inventive person can patch the existing hole and, by adding reinforcement, remount in the same location.

These racks are secured to a pair of metal brackets on the wall with the rack fastened to the brackets by small screws on the undersides. To repair it loosen or remove the screws underneath and then lift the rack off. Then deal with remounting on the side that pulled out.

Oftentimes the original installation was inferior and damaged the drywall, leading to premature failure. The traditional mounting for a towel rack is plastic anchors which require drilling a small hole (3/8" dia or less) in the drywall.

Newer anchors don't require drilling. These have a sharp end that can be forced into the drywall and then plastic threads which pull the anchor into the drywall when twisted. The metal screw for the bracket is screwed into the center of the plastic anchor.

However, in this situation you have a large hole which invites a possible quick repair with one of the new [Wingit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/WingIts-World-s-Strongest-Fastener-Super-Duty-6-Anchors-RC-MAWSD35-6/202552914?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD25H%7CMulti%7CNA%7CPLA%7C71700000032394431%7C58700003837562549%7C92700030712663209&gclid=CjwKCAjw-8nbBRBnEiwAqWt1zfgTdRPlpEqfQGsVDrTlSQgipd_99r16pUCzkE2wmnIlU-La2MmBphoCoIAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CK7KhrjH7NwCFcIXgQod6LAHwQ) type anchors intended for grab bars. This might or might not work, but I for one would consider it. The Wingit screw has a rather large head and you'd need to be sure that the existing brackets would accept that.

If I were installing towel racks in a rental property I would consider the [Wingits towel bars](https://wingits.com/products/type/towel_bars). I happen to think that tubs and showers should be fitted with grab bars even without elderly or disabled users. Stepping into a tub has some risk. The shower may have been turned on but is not up to temperature and the person steps in quickly and off balance to avoid cold spray. At the very least have an 18" or 24" vertical bar at the entrance to the tub and a long (36", 42", 48") bar horizontal on the long wall.

[image: Base level Wingit 3/4" diameter hole] Base level Wingit requires 3/4" diameter hole

If I were going to use a Wingit for a towel bar, I would plan on using only one per side because of the hole spacing on the standard towel bar. The recommended drill bit is the Wingit Apache200 carbide 3/4" drill bit, but anything that will cut a 3/4" hole in the wall should work. I can imagine trying the tip of a drywall saw if I had to (but would probably regret that).

**EDIT** The following type of drywall anchor works amazingly well and requires no power tools for installation. It does work in undamaged drywall. [Screw-in plastic drywall anchors](https://www.grainger.com/product/15X735?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!281733297965!!!g!470582336159!&ef_id=Wb6hZAAABW5VfXMN:20180814185800:s)

One product for a drywall repair is shown here: [Insta-Back Drywall Repair kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJqyQBzwlmI)

Comment: +1 Other products which'll work for large holes: grip-it, or spring toggles. Spring toggles probably being the most forgiving of an uneven hole.

Comment: Great answer, but wouldn't it profit from a simple explanation on how to fix a large-ish small hole in a drywall? sand it down some, remove loose pieces, find a spare piece of drywall that fits, or make it fit, get a reinforcement patch, apply paste, fix it, apply paste around it, let dry and sand down / paint.

Comment: I started using metal drywall clips by Hyde to hold small patches with fiberglass tape or commercial patch and mud on the joint.  But I have never felt satisfied with any simple patching technique as far as supporting anchors because the paper on the back side is not continuous.  It seems to me that inserting wood behind the patch is the only way to make a structurally strong patch.

Comment: The Wingit link is dead. All I get is the message “Access Denied: You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/p/WingIts-World-s-Strongest-Fastener-Super-Duty-6-Anchors-RC-MAWSD35-6/202552914?" on this server.” Maybe you could inline an image or something in the answer itself?

Comment: Link works for me, but I added a picture of what I think is the base level Wingit $15 for 6 so $2.50 each. There is a range of these Wingits with the most expensive stainless steel one costing $30 each and rated at 800 lb pull out force (in suitable walls) and requiring a 1.25" diameter hole.

Answer (score 15):

This happens when bathroom fixtures are only fastened to drywall -- such fixtures are easily ripped out. *If you have young children, they will be mysteriously compelled to swing like monkeys from these. Don't ask how I know.*

Here's how I permanently fix such fixtures:

1. Remove the fixture, if it's still partially attached to the wall.
2. Use a 3" [hole saw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_saw) to drill a circle through the drywall where the drywall fasteners were previously located. For now, let's assume you drilled two holes.
3. Cut two 6" lengths of 1" x 2" pine. Tie a string around these, and staple it also.
4. Insert a piece of pine in the hole, carefully holding the string. Center the pine in the hole and fasten the top and bottom of the pine with drywall screws. Repeat for the other hole.
5. From a scrap of drywall, use the 3" hole saw to cut two drywall circles to replace the damaged ones from step 2.
6. Insert a replacement drywall circle in each hole, center it, press it against the 1" x 2" pine from step 4, and fasten with drywall screws.
7. Use drywall compound & paint to hide the repairs.
8. Reattach the fixture exactly where it used to be. Because there's now 1" x 2" pine behind the drywall, you can use real screws to fasten it, and not those terrible drywall fasteners.

This is a very easy and permanent repair, and the only step that takes time is waiting for the drywall compound to dry.

If you need something stronger, you can use a larger hole saw (say 4" or 5") and a stronger piece of wood (say 1" x 3" pine or a piece of plywood). You can also slather one face of the pine with carpenters glue before you insert it into the hole.

[image: Ripped out drywall fastener]
[image: Drill 3" hole where previously fastened]
[image: 1" x 2" x 6" pine]
[image: 1" x 2" pine fastened inside drywall]
[image: Replacement drywall circle fastened to pine]
[image: Drywall compound to hide repairs]

Comment: A cheaper option (if you have no scrap wood) is to buy those stacks of wooden shims they sell at big boxes. Take 2 of them, stack them, and do the same work

Answer (score 13):

#### Get to the Studs

Regular anchors are fine for an ordinary towel bar. But not for a grab bar. For regular anchors to work here, you would need to (a) patch the drywall, (b) install the towel bar with heavy-duty anchors and hope the patch is strong enough to hold them and (c) teach the tenant - and future tenants - to not use the towel bar as a grab bar.

The problem, as is often the case, is location. Based on the picture, it appears quite natural that this towel bar would get used occasionally as a grab bar, so the problem could easily happen again.

The solution is to install a real grab bar **or** reinstall the towel bar with the same (or close to) holding power as a grab bar. To do that, you need to get into the studs.

The wall section is very short, so there may be a stud in the middle, but more likely just at the ends. I would do the following:

- Remove the other end of the towel bar.
- Cut a short piece of wood - e.g., 1" x 4", length cut to fit between the tile and the doorway.
- Install it over the existing drywall holes (the big new hold and the small anchor holes on the other end). Now you don't need to patch the drywall. **Make sure you screw into at least one stud, preferably two.** If you can only hit one stud, use heavy-duty anchors in two evenly spaced other locations along the wood.
- Paint the wood to match either the existing wall color or the trim/tile. Use a gloss or semi-gloss finish for durability. You could also stain it, but from the picture I think paint to match wall or trim would look better.
- Install the towel bar on the wood using wood screws.

Comment: Oftentimes studs or blocking is not present at the desired location. There are now anchors that are for all practical and legal purposes just as good as screwing into structural wood.  In fact some of these products advertise that they obviate the need for installing blocking in a shower renovation or new construction. Wingits are a leading product line and others are copying them.

Comment: My concern with Wingits (which I've never used but I looked at the information and they do seem to be quite heavy-duty) or other heavy-duty anchors is that in the end you are still relying on the strength of the drywall. In a case like this one (unlike installing on a new wall), there is significant damage. So installation using Wingits or similar anchors would really be dependent on cutting out a larger section of drywall and patching it securely, sanding, painting, etc. That is, in my opinion, likely to be more work than installing a board behind the full length of the towel bar.

Comment: What would you think about cutting out a rectangular section of drywall and replacing it with a board of comparable thickness (possibly reinforcing the area between the studs by screwing a second piece to it) if the drywall is only 1/2"), and then using something like a wallpaper accent to cover the board and the gaps above and below?  I'm of the opinion that hanging towels in bathrooms should be able to serve as emergency hand holds.  Even if a bar gives way, it may be able to transfer some momentum first (thus avoiding or reducing injury), and a good mounting job should accommodate that.

Comment: @supercat That would work. There is also another "hidden" alternative: Cut out a rectangular section of drywall, sneak a somewhat larger (e.g., ideally at least 2" larger on in at least 2 directions) piece of wood (probably plywood) through the hole, screw through the "extra" section to hold it in place, put a piece of drywall in the (now wood-backed) hole, patch & paint. That has the advantage of providing strength without changing the look (and paintability, etc.) of the drywall. Then use screws instead of anchors to hold the towel bar.

Comment: The above procedures would work, but are more elaborate and heavy duty than needed. The goal in a design is to build something that just barely meets the design criteria.

Comment: @JimStewart: Is it better to build something that last until the next time somebody slips and grabs it, whereupon it will need repair again, or is it better to construct something that will withstand usage as an emergency grab bar?

Comment: A good towel bar is deigned to withstand some forces beyond hanging a towel on it. The design of the better towel bars takes into account extra forces. My remark about just barely meeting the design criteria cannot be taken to mean that normal use of a towel bar would only be supporting a towel. I for one would be willing to pay 3 or 4 times the price of a minimum bar to have one that never gets loose and that I can hang on to stand on one foot, but not everybody can or will.

Answer (score 9):

Since this is being used as a handrail, perhaps it should be supplemented by a proper **vertically-mounted** hand rail at the corner?

You could replace the existing towel rail with something thinner, perfectly adequate for holding towels but too thin to be a handrail.

[image: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Yq0qPFXXXXaJXFXXq6xXFXXXM/Xueqin-Banheiro-Chuveiro-Banheira-Aperto-de-M-o-de-A-o-Inoxid-vel-Trilho-de-Suporte.jpg]

---

Second option could be to add a backing board behind the rail.  This will help spread the load over larger area,

[image: https://twincitieschick.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/photo-2.jpg]

Sorry photo's not quite relevant, but a large piece of 150x25mm board (6 inch by 1 inch) painted/stained/sealed to protect it from the moisture, and then edged for prettiness would help spread the load.  It should be wider and screwed into studs.

Comment: I have seen grab bars with diameter of 7/8", 1.25" and 1.5". I have used the 7/8" ones 24" long (in white) for towel bars, and screwed them into studs. They never come loose, and are great for a hand hold, but are not really aesthetic. They are more trouble to take off compared to a standard towel bar and cost twice as much.

Answer (score 3):

Patching the wall is simple enough: get some fiberglass mesh (you can sometimes find kits with a sufficient patch size) and fill the hole with spackle. Sand, hit it a second time, final sand and you're basically ready to paint.

As to remounting... I can't tell for sure from the picture, but it looks like it was mounted with drill-in anchors. **Do not use drill-in anchors for towel racks**. They are prone to pull out just like your picture shows and they cause significant damage to the surrounding drywall when they do pull out. The reason it's a poor option here is **there's nothing on the other side to hold onto**. Even a basic plastic drywall anchor (which typically flares to better grip the wall) might not hold. I would invest in a basic toggle bolt to hold this up. They're not easy to install here but they hold exceptionally well. There are some more expensive toggle-drive bolts ([example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cobra-Anchors-1-8-in-X-2-in-Zinc-Plated-Pan-Head-Combination-Drive-Screw-in-Anchors-2-Pack-360S/202527098)) that could do the trick as well.

Comment: Four **toggle bolts**, and you're done, +1.

Answer (score 2):

patch the wall. move the rack up alittle bit and use wall anchors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really surprised by some of this "advice".  Under no circumstances, should towel rails ever be fixed to plasterboard with plugs of any kind and nothing else - ever.  They will always - always - come loose.  Placing dinky little blocks behind the plasterboard also has no chance of surviving very long.  I understand not wanting to cut sections out to insert noggings and then having to repair that damage.  If you don't want to do that, the only option is to screw a timber wall plate at least 1" or 25mm thick to the face of the wall and make sure that it spans at least two studs and then fix the towel rail to that.  If you think it looks too bland or industrial, you could embellish it with routed profile edges or decorative mouldings applied to it.  And make sure that you paint the back side of the wall plate so that it can't absorb more moisture from the air than the front of it can, particularly if there is a substantial length of it unfixed because of the location of the studs behind it.  If you don't, you risk the unfixed portion of it bending away from the wall as the back swells.